# How to write log4net info log on application start into logger with level higher than info level

Tags: logging, log4net

I would like to know if it is possible to explicitly invoke write of start info log into log file. If I use Info method and Level will be set to WARN the log will not be written at point I request. Thank you very much for the answer.

**EDIT**
Thanks to @stuartd's answer finally I solved it by the following config:

```
    <logger name="InfoLogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="WARN"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
```

and this piece of code:

```
    private static readonly log4net.ILog rootLogger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    private static readonly log4net.ILog infoLogger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("InfoLogger");
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = infoLogger != null && (rootLogger == null || !rootLogger.IsInfoEnabled) ? infoLogger : rootLogger;

    static App()
    {
        log.Info("[Application start]");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of options, but probably the easiest is to have a separate logger set at the `INFO` level just for the header text:

```
var infoLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("InfoLogger");
var yourLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("Your_Logger_Name");

// app start
infoLogger.Info("App started");

// in the app
yourLogger.Warn("Bad things happened");
```

If your stuck on how to configure this, edit your existing config into the question.